# SQL Server Query to find different names in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation here.

I have two tables:

[image]

I need a sql query which will print the Col names which are different in two tables.

For example, in this case the query should print the result as:

[image]

The reason is clear that `m` is present in Table-1 but not present in Table-2. Similar is the case with `z` which is in Table-2 but not in Table-1.

I am really stcuk here, please help.

The colum names are not case-sensitive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use NOT EXISTS to get the result:

```
select col1
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1)
union all
select col1
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3ece/4)

Or even NOT IN:

```
select col1
from table1 t1
where col1 not in (select col1
                   from table2 t2)
union all
select col1
from table2 t2
where col1 not in (select col1
                   from table1 t1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3ece/5)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will get back to you after final testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select coalesce(t1.Col1, t2.Col1)
from [Table-1] t1
full outer join [Table-2] t2 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
where t1.Col1 is null or t2.Col1 is null
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0b91/1).

Alternatively:

```
select Col1 from
(select Col1 from [Table-1] union all select Col1 from [Table-2]) sq
group by Col1 having count(*) = 1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0b91/2).

Answer (score 0):

I Think simplest one is this

```
SELECT COL1 AS ResultCol FROM TABLE1 where COL1 not in (select COL2 from TABLE2) UNION SELECT COL2 AS ResultCol FROM TABLE2 where COL2 not in (select COL1 from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tab1 table(id int,col1 varchar(1))
declare @tab2 table(id int,col1 varchar(1))
INSERT INTO @tab1
    ([id], [Col1])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'm'),
    (4, 'c')

INSERT INTO @tab2
    ([id], [Col1])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (4, 'z')





select b.id,b.col1 from
(
select a.id,a.col1,b.col1 x from @tab1 a left join @tab2 b on a.col1 = b.col1
union
select b.id,b.col1,a.col1 x from @tab1 a right join @tab2 b on a.col1 = b.col1
 ) b
where b.x is null
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature specifically for this operation.  EXCEPT and INTERCEPT.

Find which values (single column result or multi-column result) are not present in the following queries

--What's in table A that isn't in table B

```
SELECT col1 FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT col1 FROM TableB
```

--What's in table B that isn't in table A

```
SELECT col1 FROM TableB
EXCEPT
SELECT col1 FROM TableA
```

Likewise, the INTERCEPT keyword tells you what is shared

--What's in table A and table B

```
SELECT col1 FROM TableA
INTERCEPT
SELECT col1 FROM TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FULL OUTER JOIN operator.
[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.Col1, t2.Col1)) AS id,       
       COALESCE(t1.Col1, t2.Col1) AS ResultCol
FROM Table1 t1 FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE t1.Col1 IS NULL OR t2.Col1 IS NULL
```

See example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6dfc/1)